# Github pages not locating CSV file even though it works locally (Highcharts)

Tags: csv, highcharts, filepath, github-pages

I have a Highcharts line chart with data loaded from a csv file. It works fine locally but when I push it to Github pages I get the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Here is the relevant code:

```
Highcharts.chart('lineChart', {
  data: {
   csvURL: window.location.origin + '/data/combinedtime.csv'
  },
});
```

Any idea what could be causing this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. problem : "window.location.origin + '/data/combinedtime.csv'" is a  Cross-domain request, in local is the same domain
2. solve: you can use axios package to get the other domain resources, such as

```js
 this.axios.get(url).then(res=>{ 
           // your code
   })
```